# Conditional Probability. Problem reconciling terms and definitions (sample space, outcome, event, experiment, trial, independence...)

Tags: probability, independence

Let's say I ask "What is the probability of getting a Heads given that you got a Tails?". In other words, I'm asking for $P(H|T)$.

**There are 2 interpretations**:

1. We're talking about a single coin flip, so the sample space (all of the possible outcomes of this experiment) $S = \{H, T\}$, and then obviously $P(H|T) = 0$ since once we know it's a $T$ it can't be a $H$ anymore.
   It also seems that event $H$ and event $T$ are **not** independent since $P(H|T) \neq P(H)$
2. We're talking about 2 coin flips, so the sample space (still considered a single experiment, I think?) $S' = \{(H,T),(T,H),(H,H),(T,T)\}$.

Now this is confusing, because we're looking for $P(H|T)$ but there are no events $H$ or $T$ in this new sample space $S'$! As far as I know, an event cannot be a subset of an outcome (at least not a proper subset).

So how does the formula $P(H|T) = \frac{P(H \cap T)}{P(T)}$ make sense? **How does $P(H \cap T)$ make any sense since there is no such thing as event $H$ or event $T$ in $S'$**?

How does it make sense to speak about independence of coin flips if we can't make sense of the conditional proability of several coin flips?

Comment: In the second interpretation, you are looking at $P(A\mid B)$ with $A=\{(H,H),(T,H)\}$ and $B=\{(T,H),(T,T)\}$, where is the mystery?

Comment: In $P(H|T)$ $H$ and $T$ are events. But how are the events are definded for the second case ?.

Comment: @callculus, thank you for checking in. I just understood from Did's comment that I was interpreting the math notation literally, instead of realizing that $P(H)$ in this case really means $P(\{X, H\})$ and $P(T)$ really means $P(\{T, X\})$, where $X$ is anything for the first of second flip. In other words, "probability of H" really means "probability of H on the second flip"

Comment: @Did, see my reply to callculus's comment. It makes sense now, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff It all depends on the definition of the events. Then it is correct to define $H$ as the event of getting head on the second flip and $T$ as the event of getting tail on the first flip.  Then $P(H|T)=P(H)=0.5$ because the events $H$ and $T$ are independent.

Comment: @callculus, right, it makes sense now. I think I was stuck being too literal with my translations from english into mathematical notation. Not the first time...

Comment: On the other hoof, if $H$ is instead interpreted as the event of obtaining *at least one* head and $T$ the event of obtaining *at least one* tail, then $~\mathsf P(H\mid T) = 2/3~$ because *that* $H$ and $T$ are not independent but also not exclusive. $$\mathsf P(\omega\in\{(H,T), (H,H),(T,H)\}\mid\omega\in\{(H,T),(T,H),(T,T)\})=\tfrac 23$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp, Thanks Graham. That's one of the things I was confused about. I was failing to translate "given that you got a tails" into "given that you got a tails on the first flip" in my problem. So I would sum too many elements for my condition and then come up with $\frac{2}{3}$, concluding that the events weren't independent and driving myself nuts in the process. It's finally clear, and now I've moved on to trying to build intuition as to why $P(A|B) = P(A)$ iff $P(A \cap B ) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$. I can "prove" it algebraically but I can't "see" it very clearly yet.